# home_url on IIS missing permalink index.php

Tags: permalinks, iis, site-url, home-url

I'm using IIS without any URL re-writing that include an index.php at the end. The custom permalink structure is: `/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`

The problem is that the home_url function doesn't include the index.php, so if I want to refer to a custom page `<?php echo home_url() . '/my-page/'; ?>` returns http://domain.com/my-page/ but what I need is http://domain.com/index.php/my-page/ .

Is there a WordPress function that will include the index.php or do I have to put in a custom bit of code?

N.B. I've tried [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+home_url+iis+index.php), but most links point to re-writing the URL which is **not** what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `home_url`:

```
add_filter( 'home_url', 'wpse102523_home_url' );
function wpse102523_home_url( $url ) {
    return $url . 'index.php/';
}
```

Reference: [Adam Brown's Filter Database](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/home_url)

Comment: Thanks for this - I was hoping for an internal WP function along the lines of base_permalink_url or some sort, but for a custom bit of code this would definitely be the neatest solution. I think that home_url normally leaves off the end slash, so the slash should be the other side of index.php i.e. `return $url . '/index.php';`

Comment: Ah following on from your Adam Brown database I spotted this function [iis7_supports_permalinks](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/iis7_supports_permalinks).

Comment: I hadn't run across that. (But then I'm not running WP on IIS.) You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

Trying the add_filter option didn't actually work for me. The code gets quite ugly as the home_url function was impacting permalinks which have index.php and all my attempts to get it working failed.

The best solution I came up with was to modify the Site Address (aka `home_url`) in General Settings to be http://domain.com/index.php. Then change the permalinks to be normal e.g. `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`. This then gets most links working. The only problem link is http://domain.com/index.php/ (note the end '/'). For me this doesn't matter as its my localhost site, but otherwise just fix that case and the site should work fine.

Just incase any one does want to carry on going down the `add_filter` route, here for my sins is my attempt:

```
<?php
if ($is_iis7 && !iis7_supports_permalinks()) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        add_filter( 'home_url', 'icc_iispb_url' );
    }
}

function icc_iispb_url($url) {
    if (strpos($url, 'index.php') === false) {
        $url = str_replace(get_option('home'), get_option('home').'/index.php', $url);
    }
    return $url;
}   
?>
```

Comment: You might want to clarify where `$is_iis7` gets set. (It appears to be a global variable, so you can add `global $iis7;`, but I'm not 100% sure that's a best practice.)

Comment: Yes - the code does get ugly, which is why I switched to modifying the site address which works much better. I only use it as they do use `$is_iis7` in the [source of the iis_supports_permalinks function](http://queryposts.com/function/iis7_supports_permalinks/).